# Multiple guild welcome bot - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Basically the problem is really simple, I know that I need to get `guild` object from `on_member_join` event, although when I was searching for solutions to my problem, I couldn't find any solution to it, documentation says that the only thing I can get from `on_member_join` event is `member` object and I didn't find any way to get guild object from it. So is there any way to verify which guild member joined (and get its `guild` object)?

Some code for context:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    AutoRolechannel = bot.get_channel(channelId1)
    CharacterAddChannel = bot.get_channel(channelId2)
    WelcommingChannel = bot.get_channel(ChannelId3)

    await WelcommingChannel.send("Hi <@!" + str(
        member.id) + ">. I'm glad to see you here.\n"
    "Please make sure to check every channel that you have been pinged on")

    ping1 = await CharacterAddChannel.send("<@!" + str(member.id) + ">")
    ping2 = await AutoRolechannel.send("<@!" + str(member.id) + ">")
    await ping1.delete()
    await ping2.delete()
```

P.S.:
I know I could achieve it by adding verification function, and forcing a player to do something upon joining a server, so I will get context of action (f.e. `add_reaction` event or some simple command like `!verificate`) but I would like to avoid  solution like this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member object actually has a reference to the guild: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild

Just use `member.guild`.